# What are the disadvantages of using Awesomium (with WPF)?

Tags: c#, web

Well it is definitely way faster than the built-in Web-Browser component of .Net Framework.
But is Awesomium slower than HttpWebRequest? Are there any drawbacks?

Right now I'm choosing Awesomium over HttpWebRequest because Awesomium has scripting support which is just what I needed for interacting with HTML forms.

I understand it is possible to submit HTML forms with HttpWebRequest via POST, however my target HTML forms have some heavy loaded AJAX stuff that deals with the input elements along with a couple of javascript encryptions on the input data (which droved me nuts).

So my question is, are there any disadvantages of using Awesomium?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use awesomium to detect where and what to put into httpwebrequest. Like what you've said, awesomium is a third party program so it could take longer time than other library.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you *do* need to be using a library that does Javascript interpretation if you need really bullet-proof user simulation.
A significant down-side is that your binaries will have bit-ness (32/64 bit) and require permissions to perform unmanaged p/invoke.

Other than that, Awesomium is a good choice - it's Windowless so you should be able to run your code inside of ASP.NET/Windows Service without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll need to take care of keeping it up-to-date yourself, instead of relying on windows update.

If you're viewing untrusted websites the browser you use should be current, since older versions often have security holes.